# Cross Domain XHR failing inspite of Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I am new to XHR and am trying to solve a simple use case. I have a web server, from where my javascript would fetch data. But instead of serving the data itself, the server would redirect the javascript XHR request to an alternate location (for example a file on Amazon's S3) to fulfill the request.

This brought me into the world of cross domain XHR, and I am unable to get even a simple example working inspite of reading a bit about it. I am adding "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" to the header in my main domain which serves the web page containing the javascript. But it does not work. What am I missing? I need this to work regardless of browser so am looking for something the initial server can do other than serving as a proxy, which defeats the purpose of offloading the request to S3.

- **Chrome** : Gives "Exception: NetworkError: DOM Exception 19" on the
  second call.
- **IE**: Shows a warning but opens second url after
  confirmation.
- **Firefox**: Just says "Exception: Faliure" on the second
  call.

**Code follows for test.php:**

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/html');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var request;
        var url1 = "data/file.csv";
        var url2 = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1293955/ng-algo";

        try
        {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                 request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
            // load data. 'false' indicates that further script
            // is not executed until data is loaded and parsed
            alert("Test1 with url: "+url1);
            request.open('GET', url1, false);
            request.send();
            alert(request.responseText);

            alert("Test2 with url: "+url2);
            request.open('GET', url2, false);
            request.send();
            alert(request.responseText);
        } catch (e) { alert("Exception: "+e.message); }

    </script>
</header>
This is a test page
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any arbitrary request (given the mix of Amazon and Stack Overflow in the question), CORS may not be enough as it's actually the remote server that has to give the permission.

For the 2nd request to succeed, `stackoverflow.com` would have to include relevant `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers in their responses that give your website permission to make the request. And whether those are included in the response or not is entirely up to Stack Exchange, in this case.

Also, by including `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the response, you're actually allowing other websites to request your page from their `origin`.

---

What you may need is a "*proxy*" script on your server. You can find a generalized solution from Ben Alman:

- http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/
- https://github.com/cowboy/php-simple-proxy

Which would allow:

```
request.open('GET', 'proxy.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url2), false);
```

Comment: Uhhh... Darn, that's not useful for my use case then! :( So I guess I need to revise my question. Is there anyway for me to be able to redirect requests dynamically to particular locations on AMAZON's S3, or any other storage location not owned by my domain?

Comment: ok Never mind, now that I understand the real question, I was able to find the answer here: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/08/amazon-s3-cross-origin-resource-sharing.html